# Android studio 3.5 recent files

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea

After updating Android Studio to version **3.5** recent files behavior got changed. When I press second-time CMD+E it enables disables an option "Show changed only". Whereas previously it just navigated me to the file below in the list.

Is it possible to change behavior to the previous by press second-time CMD+E it will just navigate to the next file?

[image]

Comment: While pressing cmd + E the first item is already got selected right?

Comment: When pressing second time it got selected.

Comment: yes right i also checked this

Comment: You can use `Tab` to move to opposite group. If you want to open specific file/tool window: just start typing it's name - IDE will select it, based on chars occurrences matched.

Comment: @Andrey I want to go to the next file below. Previously it was possible by pressing CMD+E once more